# Best way to iterate through Hashtable and conditionally remove entries in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, iteration, hashtable

In VB.NET, I have a HashTable that I would like to iterate through and conditionally remove entries from. I've written the following code that does the job perfectly, but I'd like to know if there are any creative ways to simplify the code. It just doesn't seem right to have to create a second list to perform this operation.

Here's what I've written:

```
Dim ModsToRemove As New List(Of String)
For Each ModKey As DictionaryEntry In ModHashTable
    If ModKey.Key.ToString.Contains("Criteria") Then
        ModsToRemove.Add(ModKey.Key.ToString)
    End If
Next
For Each ModKey As String In ModsToRemove
    ModHashTable.Remove(ModKey)
Next
```

Is there another way to perform the same operation that doesn't require the creation of a second list and a second loop? Is it possible to remove entries from something you are iterating through without throwing an error in VB.NET? Is doing so universally a bad idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With a little bit of help from Resharper and LINQ, you can simplify your expression in the following ways.

This code block here can be rewritten to use LINQ instead of the embedded `IF` statement

```
For Each ModKey As DictionaryEntry In ModHashTable
    If ModKey.Key.ToString.Contains("Criteria") Then
        ModsToRemove.Add(ModKey.Key.ToString)
    End If
Next
```

Is equivalent to

```
Dim modsToRemove As List(Of String) = (From modKey As DictionaryEntry In 
modHashTable Where modKey.Key.ToString.Contains("Criteria") 
Select modKey.Key.ToString).ToList()
```

Combining this with your actual loop to remove the items from the Hashtable, you should be able to get the equivalent functionality of your example above with the following 3 lines of code:

```
For Each key As String In (From modkey As DictionaryEntry In modHashTable Where modkey.Key.ToString.Contains("Criteria") Select modkey.Key.ToString).ToList()
  modHashTable.Remove(key)
Next
```

Comment: This should work, but I am bound by Option Strict On and thus get an error at modKey as DictionaryEntry: "Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Collections.DIctionaryEntry'. I'm really not sure why your code would give this error and not mine, as I essentially have the same code. at that point.

Comment: I threw in a few DirectCasts in there and got this to work. Option Strict On made this a bit more verbose, not overly so.